# Regexp to match all the characters except spaces and 4 last characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regexp for masking values except for the last 4 characters and spaces.

`1234 4567 8901 2345` => `**** **** **** 2345`

`123445678901 23 4 5` => `************ 23 4 5`

`[^\s](?=.{4,}$)` doesn't pass for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
.replace(/\d(?=.*\d(?:\s*\d){3}\s*$)/g, '*')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eXJuVh/1)

**Regex details**

- `\d` - a digit
- `(?=.*\d(?:\s*\d){3}\s*$)` - that is followed with any amount of any chars other than line break chars and then a digit, followed with three occurrences of 0+ whitespaces + a digit and then 0+ whitespaces at the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You could update the pattern to assert 4 digits at the right until the end of the string.

```
\d(?=(?:[ \d]*\d){4}$)
```

**Explanation**

- `\d` match a digit
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[ \d]*\d` Match 0+ times a space or digits followed by a single digit
  - `){4}$`  and repeat that 4 times ans assert the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FfONhc/1)

```js
[
  "1234 4567 8901 2345",
  "123445678901 23 4 5"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(/\d(?=(?:[ \d]*\d){4}$)/gm, "*")));
```

Comment: This one works for me `\w(?=(?:[ \w]*\w){4}$)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need a negative lookahead. If you have control over the input format then try this:

```js
const number = '1234 5678 9012 3456';
const masked = number.replace(/\d{4}\s/g, '**** ');
console.log(masked);
```

If you want to accept also random spaces, try this:

```js
const number = '1234 5678 9 012 3 45 6';
const masked = number.replace(/(\d\s*){4}\s/g, '**** ');
console.log(masked);
```