# Regular expression to get last 12 characters of a string (except spaces)

Tags: c#, regex

I want to use a regular expression to capture last 12 characters of a string except spaces.

2 examples:

- `COD83 8365 838     BF` => `D838365838BF`
- `COM2893 0409 7642 946` => `304097642946`

In C# code, I want to use this :

```
var input = "COD83 8365 838     BF";
var pattern = "";
var replace = "";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace);

Console.Writeline(input); //print D838365838BF
```

I read this article but don't achieve to adapt for me : [Regexp to match all the characters except spaces and 4 last characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63919718/regexp-to-match-all-the-characters-except-spaces-and-4-last-characters)

Can anyone help me?

Edit
I finnaly use this :

```
var pattern = "(.*?)((\\S)\\s*)?((\\S)\\s*)?((\\S)\\s*)?((\\S)\\s*)?((\\S)\\s*)?((\\S)\\s*)?((\\S)\\s*)?((\\S)\\s*)?((\\S)\\s*)?((\\S)\\s*)?((\\S)\\s*)?((\\S)\\s*)?$";
var replace = "$3$5$7$9$11$13$15$17$19$21$23$25";
```

Comment: Are you sure using Regex is the best way to accomplish you goal ? Is it mandatory ?
If not, maybe you can just remove the spaces and use the `Substring` function on the last 12 characters ?

Comment: `input.Replace(" ", "")[^12..]`

Comment: I use regex because pattern & replace will be set as config settings in my program, to give the user the possibility to modify the behavior of the field

Comment: The regular expression `\S(?!(?:\s*\S){12})` will match each of the last `N` non-whitespace characters in the string, where `N` is the lessor of `12` and the number of non-whitespace characters in the string. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HbcBNV/1). In Ruby, for example, `"COD83 8365 838     BF".scan(/\S(?!(?:\s*\S){12})/) #=> ["D", "8", "3", "8", "3", "6", "5", "8", "3", "8", "B", "F"]`,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This would probably be easier without regex.

```
var input = "COD83 8365 838     BF";
var noSpaces = input.Replace(" ","");
var result = noSpaces.Substring(noSpaces.Length - 12);
```

however if you wanted plain regex this would work

```
var input = "COD83 8365 838     BF";
var pattern = ".*(\\w)\\s*(\\w)\\s*(\\w)\\s*(\\w)\\s*(\\w)\\s*(\\w)\\s*(\\w)\\s*(\\w)\\s*(\\w)\\s*(\\w)\\s*(\\w)\\s*(\\w)\\s*$";
var replace = "$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10$11$12";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace);
```

Comment: I use regex because pattern & replace will be set as config settings in my program, to give the user the possibility to modify the behavior of the field

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a pattern that matches spaces, then you can use indexing to get the last 12 characters:

```c#
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var input = "COD83 8365 838     BF";
var pattern = @"\s"; // Match the spaces
var replace = ""; // Replace the matched spaces with an empty string
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace);

Console.WriteLine(result); // No spaces
Console.WriteLine(result[^12..]); // Last 12 characters
```

This is a neat reference for regex patterns in C#:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with 12 captures and anchor it to the end. Here's the unescaped regex

`(\S)\s*(\S)\s*(\S)\s*(\S)\s*(\S)\s*(\S)\s*(\S)\s*(\S)\s*(\S)\s*(\S)\s*(\S)\s*(\S)\s*$`

Or 12 named captures (x1, x2, x3, x4, ... x12):

`(?<x1>\S)\s*(?<x2>\S)\s*(?<x3>\S)\s*(?<x4>\S)\s*(?<x5>\S)\s*(?<x6>\S)\s*(?<x7>\S)\s*(?<x8>\S)\s*(?<x9>\S)\s*(?<x10>\S)\s*(?<x11>\S)\s*(?<x12>\S)\s*$`

The code to extract all 12 captures and concatenate together would exceed the amount of code to just read 12 non-chars from the end of the string.

For reference, `\S` is "capture any non-whitesapce character" and `\s` is capture any whitespace.

Comment: Please don't do this OP. You friends and family will shun you.